# MediaSource в ExoPlayer2

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

У меня возникли вопросы насчет `ConcatenatingMediaSource`.
Мне нужно воспроизвести несколько видео и каждый раз когда заканчивается одно видео, я должен проверять один метод. Но в случае с `ConcatenatingMediaSource`, он мне дает знать о завершении после самого последнего видео, то есть в конце видео списка.

```
MediaSource  mediaSource;

for(int i = 0; i < videoList.size; i++){
    mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(Application.video_path + video.getName()), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
}

ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(
            mediaSources.toArray(new MediaSource[mediaSources.size()]));

player.prepare(concatenatedSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

**Вопрос**: Как получить `STATE_ENDED` после каждого видео или как понять в `ConcatenatingMediaSource`, что завершился какое-то видео, чтобы проверять типа этого?

```
if (firstVideo = STATE_ENDED){
    textView.setText(video.getName);
//////
```

И еще возможно ли отправлять в аргументы `ExtractorMediaSource` класс вместо `uri` к файлу?